# How to get key or index name from value in array without iteration?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have a two dimensional array. I'm trying to get the key/index name of a given value. How do I do this? I went through the PHP manual and they suggest to do an iteration, but I do not want to iterate. Is there a way to do without iteration?

I would like to do something similar to

```
$country = 'Algeria';
echo $iso_countries[$country]; //obviously this will throw an error since the index does not exist. It's just an example.
```

array

```
$iso_countries = array
(
    'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
    'AX' => 'Aland Islands',
    'AL' => 'Albania',
    'DZ' => 'Algeria',
);
```

Comment: If the array is sorted by value you can do a [binary search](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/a/implementing-binary-search-of-an-array) which will find any entry in a list of 256 or fewer entries in at most 8 steps. Other than that, you'd need to pre-build an index that maps country names to their abbreviations, which is essentially what [`array_flip()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) will do.

Comment: You should also disabuse yourself of the notion that "loops are bad". Loops are fundamental to doing virtually everything and you should instead invest your effort in learning when/why loops can be _used badly_ and avoid those, rather than trying to engineer around a non-existent problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use array_search

```
$iso_countries = array
(
    'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
    'AX' => 'Aland Islands',
    'AL' => 'Albania',
    'DZ' => 'Algeria',
);

$founded = array_search('Algeria',$iso_countries);
echo $founded;
```

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way to get the key of value from an array without an explicit (`foreach`,`while`,`for`) or implicit (`in_array`,`array_flip`,`array_search`) iteration.

> PHP ARRAY MANUAL: An
>   [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in PHP
>   is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to
>   keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be
>   treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a
>   map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As
>   array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays
>   are also possible.

From the doc, array is  a map which is used to get the value from the index or key, not the contrary.

---

If you do many search with `$country`,you can flip the `$iso_contries` then use index to get the value.

```
$iso_countries = array
(
    'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
    'AX' => 'Aland Islands',
    'AL' => 'Albania',
    'DZ' => 'Algeria',
);
$iso_countries = array_flip($iso_countries);
$country = 'Algeria';
echo $iso_countries[$country];
```